# Uploading an image to Github issue with API and Python

Tags: python, image-uploading, github-api

I am using Github API to create an issue (specifically, with requests module in python).

I need to include the picture in the issue content, but I could't find any way that worked for me.

Could you please suggest something that works from python?

Thanks

Edit: It could be really easily done by Github markdowns for linking the pictures that I stored at Amazon S3.

Comment: Please edit the question and demostrate the the effort you have tried this far: your source code, exceptions you are getting, etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are already able to post things to the Issues Page of a given repository then follow these steps to post the image.
I too at first found it annoying to post pictures to github... Github uses markdown and with markdown you can theoretically use an image sourced on your computer (this I believe only works on markdown that you host) but you can also provide a link or image source which is on the internet... particularly convenient for posting pictures to github... is github or you can use dropbox, picasa, photobucket, instagram, or flixster or 20 other image hosting services on the internet, but the point is you then once the image has an `href="http://photobucket.com/myimage/3549604690"` you can now host that into your markdown file.

Like so:

```
![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg)

![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg "Optional title")
![GitHub Logo](/images/logo.png)
Format: ![Alt Text](url)
```

Meaning in my case:

```
![Screen shot of Python stuff](http://photobucket.com/myimage/3549604690 "Screen Shot")
```

[Screen shot of Python stuff http://photobucket.com/myimage/3549604690](http://photobucket.com/myimage/3549604690)
Notice that it works on stackOverflow as well.

For guides on markdown syntax:
http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img
https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/

So STEP BY STEP (if you want to do it all through Github) and not apply any other APIs then have the user:

1. Create a new Github Repo or use their existing repo. (Your choice).
2. Make a post request to insert the image inside the repository's files.
3. Post the issue to the repository and now use the url of the image
   where it was hosted. From what I've seen when images are added to a
   repository they go to the path:
   `https://github.com/myUser/PictureHoster/blob/master/myscreenshot.jpg`.

> Python should brush my teeth! I tried to get it to work and here: `![Screen shot of Python
>   stuff](https://github.com/myUser/PictureHoster/blob/master/myscreenshot.jpg
>   "Screen Shot")` it is not working.

. 
(Or something like that to find out I would go to your github page click on repositories click on the image inside your repo then right click on it once it's open and do copy Image URL).
Basically to use a different picture hosting service you do the same right click on it inside your flixster account and copy/paste that image url.

Comment: Thank you! I am doing exactly that but I'm gonna host my pictures at Amazon S3.